# Create Elasticsearch index with non mandatory field for sorting

Tags: elasticsearch, spring-data-elasticsearch

I'm using SpringData Elasticsearch 3.2 and have an document with a non mandatory field called dueDate. Users are able to sort documents based on the dueDate field if it's populated.

Once I create the index and create documents without a dueDate, I get an exception saying there is no dueDate field in the index when trying to list the documents. If I create the index and create documents with a due date, the list documents works as expected.

Is there a way I force the index (preferably via Java annotation) to have a dueDate field even if the value is null or list the documents without throwing an exception?

Comment: Are you creating mapping dynamically or it exists before pushing first document

Comment: It's getting created dynamically. So if the first document does not have a dueDate, the index is created without the field.

Comment: You will need to create mapping before indexing if you want to sort on "dueDate" field. Also creating a dynamic mapping can have unintended consequences like date getting indexed as string. If in future a new field comes it will still get indexed(dynamically)

Comment: I wanted to avoid that. I'm using annotations in the domain object (e.g. @Field(type = FieldType.Date) to dictate field types.

Answer (score 0):

1. You need to create mapping before indexing documents. You will still be able to index documents if field not present in mapping.
2. Use scripting in sorting(it's performance will be less than option 1).

```
{
  "query": {
    "match_all": {}
  },
  "sort" : {
        "_script" : {
            "type" : "number",
            "script" : {
                "lang": "painless",
                "source": "if(doc['dueDate'].size()!=0){doc['dueDate'].value.getMillis()}"
            },
            "order" : "desc"
        }
    }
}
```

if(doc['dueDate'].size()!=0)--> to check if field exists.

doc['dueDate'].value.getMillis() -- converts date to milli seconds( number)

EDIT1:

```
GET index27/_search
{
  "query": {
    "match_all": {}
  },
  "sort": [{
        "_script": {
            "type": "number",
            "script": {
                "lang": "painless",
                "inline": "if(doc['dueDate'].size()!=0) { return doc['dueDate'].value.getMillis();} else{  new Date().getTime();}"
            },
            "order": "asc"
        }
    }]
}
```

new Date().getTime() will give current date . It is used in case you need documents with due date to be at top

Comment: I have added an edit , as documents with due date were not returned on top

Answer (score 0):

What type is your `dueDate` field? And which mapper do you use - the Jackson based `DefaultEntityMapper` or the `ElasticsearchEntityMapper`?

I'd recommend to use the latter and define the property in your class with the following annotation (changing the pattern to the format you need):

```
@Field(type = FieldType.Date, format = DateFormat.custom, pattern = "YYYYMMDD")
private String dueDate;
```

If you are using Spring Data Elasticsearch repositories this will create the mapping when the index is created by the repository on startup. Otherwise you can use the `ElasticsearchOperations.putMapping(Class<T>)` method or one of it's overloads to write the mapping to the index.